# How to insert new array to current array C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with my C#. 
I have query

```
string query1 = "select userid, name, lastname from user";
string query2 = "select branch from branch";

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, cn))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader1.Read())
                    {
                       objs.Add(new {

                        userID          = reader1["userID"],
                        username        = reader1["name"],
                        SPFCount        = reader1["lastname"]
                       } );
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }


 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString.ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, cn))
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader2.Read())
                        {
                           objs.Add(new {

                            userID          = reader2["branch"],
                           } );
                        }
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                }

 return serializer.Serialize(objs);
```

I got array from query 1 `{userid:'test',name:'nameok',lastname:'lastname'}`

I got array from query 2 `{branch:'branch1'}`

how I can merge the 2 array into one, so my output would be like

```
{userid:'test',name:'nameok',lastname:'lastname',branch:'branch1'}
```

I really need your helps. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because your model is a list of invoices.  Which invoice out of the ones in the list did you want to look at for the PI_ID?  If your view is only supposed to have one invoice, then don't use `List<Models.invoice>`, and use `Models.invoice` instead.

Once you start only sending a single invoice, then you can reference it as `@Model.PI_ID`

Comment: Hello, I have another looping in database, the PI_ID is duplicate, so I want to show that onetime.

Comment: Update the question with details please

Comment: Then use `@Model.First().PI_ID`